# is there any third party tool to create static library for armv6/armv7?

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, arm, static-libraries

I have some source code in `C/C++`. I have to make static library to use in my iPhone application. is there any third party tool to create static library for armv6/armv7 ?

Comment: I am doing the same thing by just writing the c/c++ code in XCODE in .mm files and getting the library as of now it works fine... :/

Comment: Please could you tell me the steps to create .a files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link will help you create a static library in xcode ...

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

just rename the .m file to .mm file and write your c/c++ implementation code in it....

try it for a small function first and if it works for you can implement all your classes in it...

Please make sure when you try to use this library in any other project in XCODE , only use .mm extension for all your files even the appdelegate... hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [iOS Universal Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework). I have used it to create a number of static frameworks that I link against my application projects. It works like a charm and is really easy to setup - no need to come up with your own complicated shell scripts.

It adds a template for a new target project type, which you can then import and use just like an ordinary Apple framework. I would recommend setting up a workspace containing both the framework project and application project, that way the dependencies are handled automatically by Xcode.

Comment: I followed the steps with "iOS Universal Framework". But it created a framework like file.framework. Its size also too big more than 58MB. Is there any way to create .a file ?

Comment: Sorry yes, this will create .framework files. Is there a reason you are looking for a third party tool, rather than just using the built-in Cocoa Touch Static Library project template? This creates a target that builds a `.a` file.

Comment: I am working in third party api (PJSIP). I want to integrate x API in PJSIP. PJSIP is in C. x API is in C++. If I want to integrate both of them, i have to create static library using x API. Then I will use that static library in PJSIP.

Comment: Objective-C++ (.mm) files should be sufficient for the C and C++ code? Have you _tried_ using the standard static library template? Beyond that I don't know I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you DO NOT WANT to link to a static lib that is made with another compiler than the one used to compile the lib. Static libs are not really portable between compilers, since static lib formats are not covered by C/C++ standards. Due to name mangling and other formatting differences, you may not be able to link at all, or worse, it seems to work but injects bugs. Worse, if you use the standard library from your compiler in your lib, it will create horrible name collisions when someone links to your lib and they don't use an IDENTICAL version of the standard library!

Publish the lib using the compiler you expect them to be using. And if you must use the standard library, then you have to make sure they have the same version you have. Really, you should just have them compile the lib themselves or prebuild it for each compiler you support. It sucks, but that's the reality of it as it stands today.